# Clone git submodules with their .git directory

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is it possible to clone a repository with its submodules and have their `.git` directory be at `./submodule/.git` instead of `./.git/modules/submodule`?

Some tools in the submodule repository expect `.git` to be a directory.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but you should provide feedback to the authors of those tools, .git can be a file when dealing with worktrees and similar functions, it is incorrect of them to assume .git will be the repository directory.

Comment: There are also other instances where it makes sense to have a .git directory in the module rather than the parent. For example when volume mounting the submodule into a Docker container being utilized as a development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this.  That's how Git submodules *used* to work, but quite a while ago, Git was changed to put them all into the `.git/modules/` of the superproject.<sup>1</sup>  The `git submodule` command has (since Git 2.12) an `absorbgitdirs` subcommand to move from the old way to the new way, but there is no subcommand to move from the new arrangement back to the old one.

---

<sup>1</sup>See commit [501770e1bb5d13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/501770e1bb5d132ae4f79aa96715f07f6b84e1f6).  The new behavior began as of Git 1.7.8.